# Searching for SciFi book where a battle android gets rediscovered by scavengers

Tags: story-identification, novel, androids

I read a book a few years back and I can't seem to find it again.

What I remember about the story:

- In the beginning a couple of scavengers land on a moon or asteroid to scavenge an old military facility
- there is one scavenger team and one lone scavenger who fight over the goods
- a still functional combat android reactivates and starts to hunts the scavengers
- I believe the combat android looked like a woman
- the combat android kills the scavenger team and leaves with the lone one

The only other thing i can remember is that at some point the android goes into a tar lake which has an old battlefield under it to get its hands on materials for repairs.

That's pretty much all I can remember. Would be great if somebody could help me out.

Comment: I would like to read that one. Hope someone IDs it.

Comment: Except for the android thing, there are a couple of Bolo stories that go in that direction.

Comment: @LSerni, that was my first thought, but it doesn't ring any bells. I hope someone IDs this one, I want to read it.

Comment: @zeta-band Me too: I got some great reading suggestions here on SciFi.SE.

Comment: While looking for this book i noticed how hard it is to google for cyborg or android books. When i looked for "cyborg" i found pages of erotic literature with cyborg lovers. And as soon as you add "android" to the search you only get google playstore links or forums for android apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. That's a bit embarrassing. Just found the book in my Amazon Kindle library. Looks like I bought, read and forgot about it.

It was:

**My Outcast State** (The Maauro Chronicles Book 1)
by Edward McKeown

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25739499-my-outcast-state

[image]

Looks like there's even a second book out now.

Comment: I saw that. Still have to wait 19 hours. Thank you!